# Selenium Chrom Webdriver install

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I've been trying to get into web automation for Chrome and I decided to try out Selenium. To begin I wrote the following lines:

`from selenium import webdriver
f = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/NAME/Downloads/chromedriver/")`

I am very positive that this path is correct but I am still confronted by the following error:

`NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/NAME/Downloads/chromedriver/'`

Comment: is this Windows? try: `f = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/NAME/Downloads/chromedriver/")`

Comment: try it without the/ after chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this.

```
f = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/NAME/Downloads/chromedriver")
```

the slash indicates that chromedriver is a folder rather than a file.